# Hot key with formatting

Tags: .net, wpf, hotkeys

The underscore does not hotkey
It there a way to format a textblock and still hotkey

```
<Button  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" x:Name="btnClearSearch"   
         Click="ClearSearch_Click">
    <Button.Content>
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Style="{StaticResource RunSymbol}">&#xE106;</Run>
            <Run Style="{StaticResource Button}">_Clear</Run>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not add a hotkey to a TextBlock, as it is different than a label and is not actually an interactable `Control`, but a `FrameworkElement`.

See [Differences between Label and TextBlock](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/). In this case, you will need to use a Label and play around with the margin and padding to get it to look the same as two Runs in a TextBlock.

You may also want to look at the [AccessText](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-accesstext/) control.

Comment: Thanks tried AccessText and could not get it to format.  I will give Label a try